# Adding custom option to menu items in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I would like to add a dropdown field to the existing menu items in menu editor in wordpress. For example,When I add a page/post to the menu,I get a collapsible panel,in which there are navigation field & title attribute.Here I want to add one more field which will be a dropdown. Can someone help me with some source to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

please check this out hope you will use this 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/